# Fund my Ropsten account to deploy my contract

Tags: truffle, ropsten

I have a full geth node on my machine and I want to deploy my contract on Ropsten using truffle.

How I can fund my coinable account with some ether to deploy my smart contract?

I have tried [fuusent.ropsten](https://faucet.ropsten.be) but it says " invalid address"

I have account in metamask and it has some ether but I did not know how to use it.

how can I add some ether to any account I created in Ropsten to use it to deploy the smart contract and to interact with it later after deploy it

I want many account to interact with my smart contract. I used the command `geth --ropsten account creat` but I don't know how to fund all theses accounts

In truffle.js I have this:

```
ropsten: {
  
 host: "Localhost",     // Localhost (default: none)
 port: 8545 ,           // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
 network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
 
},
```

In a terminal I connect to the node as the following:

```
geth --syncmode "fast" --cache=1048 --ropsten --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545 console
```

Then in another terminal I deploy the smart contract using truffle as the following:

```
Truffle migrate --network ropsten
```

and it does not work as this error appear:

```
1_initial_migration.js
======================

 Deploying 'Migrations'
  ----------------------

 Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

 "Migrations" could not deploy due to insufficient funds
    * Account:  0xd48616a728b4D05A5b0e6457EBda383A92f40A54
    * Balance:  0 wei
    * Message:  sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: 372936000000000 and the sender's account only has: 0
    * Try:
      + Using an adequately funded account
      + If you are using a local Geth node, verify that your node is synced.
```

When I check the address balance, it returns 0:

```
> eth.getBalance("0xd48616a728b4d05a5b0e6457ebda383a92f40a54")
0
```

Comment: https://faucet.ropsten.be/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how long it take to get the ethers? because I did it but no ether and when I try again it says I am in greylist and then "Invalid address".

Comment: usually directly... what is the address you try to send ether to?

Comment: 0xd48616a728b4d05a5b0e6457ebda383a92f40a54, Thanks

Comment: Should I add somewhere else and I did not ?

Comment: this address has 5 Ether
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xd48616a728b4d05a5b0e6457ebda383a92f40a54
how are you connecting to Ropsten?

Comment: I think your geth does not sync correctly for some reason. use https://infura.io/  to connect to an available node onRopsten.. it is much easier.

Comment: and by the way (even if you have balance your tx will fail), you need to use hdwallet-provider from truffle or something else to add your private key and sign the transaction..

Comment: Is infura suport events? I used infura but it did not work to listen to many events in my code. It worked if I have one event, if I add the code in my frontend to listen to another events in python web3.py it shows error

Comment: I think yes you need to use WebSockets and with java, I was able to look for events between a certain amount of blocks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of faucets you can try:

- https://faucet.ropsten.be
- https://faucet.kyber.network
- https://faucet.metamask.io

Some of these may require MetaMask to be installed, or some kind of authentication, to prevent someone from spamming. You can find a list for other Ethereum testnets here: https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/getting-started/where-to-get-testnet-ether